# how to rollback the ignore state of a file/folder in git using eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git

accidently I set the ignore state for a folder in GIT in eclipse.

context-menu on the folder -> team -> ignore.

How can I activate this folder for GIT again ?

I guess it must be team -> add to index, but this doesn't work for me.

any help ?

Answer (score 3):

1. Click Ctrl+shift+R and type .gitignore in eclipse.
2. Open the .gitignore file of respective project.
3. All the ignored file's path will be displayed here.
4. Now remove the paths of files which you want to unignore and save it.
5. Again the files will be back to its original stage and can be added to staging area.

Answer (score 2):

[Steps to make file unAssumed ignore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QLrL.jpg)
If you don't want your files to be ignored then do the following

Go to the file you don't want to be ignored and rightclick it --> Team --> Advanced --> No Assume Unchanged

Please find the same in image

Comment: this was the only way that it worked for me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

See this [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=407994) right now there is no way to find all ignored resource in a git repo using EGIT.

When you do `Team context-menu on the folder -> team -> ignore` it will automatically create a **.gitignore** file inside the parent folder and this file is added automatically to git index and will be shown in git staging view.

After committing this file it is difficult to find all ignored resources in a given git repo. Go to your file explorer and search for all **.gitignore** files inside a git repo and view their content.

Comment: Did not work, I tried @Raghav2650 way and then it worked...

Answer (score 0):

In the base directory of the git project, there will be a file called .gitignore (Note the dot at the start of the filename).

This file lists all the files, directories etc that are ignored by git.

Simply edit that file, removing the line which corresponds to the folder you accidentally added.

Comment: this didn't work for me, I had to do the steps described by @Raghav2650 and it worked.